# Not able to compare NAN using Expression

Tags: wpf, linq, lambda, expression

I'm using Expression to compare values and i'm using the below code,

Below method creating lambda expression.

```
    public static class Test
{
    public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> TransformToPredicate<T>(Expression<Func<T, double>> getvalue, double value)
    {
        System.Linq.Expressions.Expression equals = System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Equal(getvalue.Body,
                                             System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Constant(value));
        return System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(equals, getvalue.Parameters);
    }
}
```

In the below code while comparing Nan with Nan value it returns false. How to overcome this when using Expressioons? I need do this in more generic way?

```
           Employee emp = new Employee();
        emp.SickLeaveHours = double.NaN;
        Expression<Func<Employee, double>> getfunc = x => x.SickLeaveHours;
        var predicate = Test.TransformToPredicate<Employee>(getfunc, double.NaN);
        var func = predicate.Compile();
        var flag = func(emp);
```

Below code works fine when i use other than Nan value.

```
            Employee emp = new Employee();
        emp.SickLeaveHours = 10.0;
        Expression<Func<Employee, double>> getfunc = x => x.SickLeaveHours;
        var predicate = Test.TransformToPredicate<Employee>(getfunc, 10.0);
        var func = predicate.Compile();
        var flag = func(emp);
```

I know double.Nan == double.Nan will return false and we have to use either double.IsNAN or value != value. But i'm not sure how to do this when using Expressions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are comparing by object reference. That is why you always get false returned. However every type provides `Equals()` method. In order to compare two double or any two same types, you should call their `Equals` function. Calling equals function is not the same as *`Expression.Equal`*.

Here is a demo:

```
var wrong =
    System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Lambda<Func<bool>>(
    System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Equal(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Constant(double.NaN),
    System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Constant(double.NaN))).Compile();

// is always false
bool result = wrong();

ConstantExpression first = System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Constant(double.NaN, typeof(double));
ConstantExpression second = System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Constant(double.NaN, typeof(double));

var right =
    System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Lambda<Func<bool>>(
    System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Call(first, first.Type.GetMethod("Equals", new[] { second.Type }), second)).Compile();

// will always be true
result = right();
```